# How to downgrade tensorflow version in colab?

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am using `pip3 install tensorflow==1.8.0`, but it doesn't have GPU support.

So I am using `pip3 install tensorflow-gpu==1.8.0`, but it still raises an exception

> libcudart.so.VERSION No such file.

Should I use `colab` to install `tensorflow` from source?

After `pip3 list`:

```
tensorboard              1.10.0   
tensorflow               1.10.0   
tensorflow-hub           0.1.1
```

Answer (score 40):

You can downgrade Tensorflow to a previous version without GPU support on Google Colab. I ran:

```py
!pip install tensorflow==1.14.0
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

which initially returned

```
2.0.0-dev20190130
```

but when I returned to it after a few hours, I got the version I requested:

```
1.14.0
```

Trying to downgrade to a version with GPU support:

```py
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0
```

requires restarting the runtime and fails, as importing `import tensorflow as tf` returns:

```
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

### Update

When the import fails you can always downgrade CUDA to version 9.0 using following commands

```py
!wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/9.0/Prod/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-9-0-local_9.0.176-1_amd64-deb
!dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-9-0-local_9.0.176-1_amd64-deb
!apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-9-0-local/7fa2af80.pub
!apt-get update
!apt-get install cuda=9.0.176-1
```

You can check the version of CUDA by running:

```py
!nvcc --version
```

### Second update

This code now seems to fail, see the follow-up question at [How to downgrade to tensorflow-gpu version 1.12 in google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62357382/how-to-downgrade-to-tensorflow-gpu-version-1-12-in-google-colab)

Comment: I know it's illegal but I have to say: worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @emremrah What is illegal in the answer?

Comment: @user4052054 StackExchange discourages comments saying "thank you" or "+1". emremah probably knows about it and took the risk. I don't think anything in the answer is illegal.

Comment: @miguelmorin Nice, for a moment I thought that using `dpkg` or `apt-key` was against Colab's terms of service or something.

Comment: Well using pip install in Colab is not recommended since it builds tf from source to ensure compatibility. Using pip may not be very beneficial.

Comment: @miguelmorin I tried this but, this does not work anymore. I get "dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from 'cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-9-0-local_9.0.176-1_amd64-deb' to decompressor pipe: unexpected end of file or stream "  error and some other errors followed by that. Can you give me an solution. I need tf-gpu=1.12 installed on my colab

Comment: @GayalKuruppu This solution was a year and a half ago and I no longer use Google Colab. I suggest asking a new question and referencing this answer.

Comment: @miguelmorin I did, can you help me with it? https://stackoverflow.com/q/62357382/7876086

Comment: @GayalKuruppu I'm afraid I no longer use Google Colab so I can't help you. I added your question in an update to my answer.

Answer (score 40):

Google recommends you not to do pip installs!!!!

1. use this instead: `%tensorflow_version 1.x`
2. Restart the Runtime and check if its changed:

```py
import tensorflow
print(tensorflow.__version__)
```

Here is a link to the main article:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tensorflow_version.ipynb#scrollTo=8UvRkm1JGUrk

Comment: FYI, by default it takes tensorflow version 1.15.2. To use lesser version than this you need to do pip install

Comment: IMO, this should've been the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

[Google](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tensorflow_version.ipynb) gives quite a simple solution to downgrade to the previously used Colab tf v.1.15.2. Just run the following magic line in Colab:

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
```

Ther recommend "against using *pip install* to specify a particular TensorFlow version for both GPU and TPU backends. Colab builds TensorFlow from the source to ensure compatibility with our fleet of accelerators. **Versions of TensorFlow fetched from PyPI by pip may suffer from performance problems or may not work at all**".  This means if you need GPU support, use one of the two given TF versions. The other versions will not necessary work I guess even for CPU.

Comment: Yes, this really works. But one thing need be noted: we need run this line: "%tensorflow_version 1.x" before we running any other codes else in the connection session, or even we ran this line, the tensorflow version will be still 2.8.

Comment: By using this line I got this error : ValueError: Tensorflow 1 is unsupported in Colab. How can I fix it?

Comment: My answer isn't probably valid anymore with changes in colab env

Answer (score 1):

The build process for GPU-enabled tensorflow is involved. In particular, old versions of TensorFlow use (or require) older versions of CUDA, which itself depends on system libraries and configuration beyond the scope of a `pip install`.

I suspect that downgrading TensorFlow on a VM configured for a newer version is going to be an involved process, perhaps involving downgrades / reinstalls of system libraries.

If it's practical, it might be simpler to update your code to use the latest version of TensorFlow, at least until Colab supports persistent backend enivronments.

Answer (score 1):

`%tensorflow_version 1.x` no longer works.

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8d2919c1d33c> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('tensorflow_version', '1.x')

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/colab/_tensorflow_magics.py in _tensorflow_version(line)
     33 
     34   if line.startswith("1"):
---> 35     raise ValueError(
     36         # pylint: disable=line-too-long
     37         textwrap.dedent("""\

ValueError: Tensorflow 1 is unsupported in Colab.

Your notebook should be updated to use Tensorflow 2.
See the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#migrate-from-tensorflow-1x-to-tensorflow-2.
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that only tensorflow 2 is supported by Colab, but that's not true, you still can use pip to uninstall tensorflow 2 and install a specific version of tf1. `!yes|pip uninstall tensorflow`, `!pip install tensorflow==1.15.5` Maybe you should install other dependencies. So use `!pip install -r requirements.txt` Attention! You must restart the runtime in order to use newly installed versions.

Comment: pip install tensorflow==1.15.5 does not work still