# Eager execution in Tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I am testing code on Google Colab. It seems that Google Colab runs the version 2 of Tensorflow by default:

```
[In:]
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

[Out:]
2.0.0-dev20190130
```

and that this version does not have eager execution:

```
[In:]
tf.enable_eager_execution()

[Out:]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-ddf3115bdcc7> in <module>()
----> 1 tf.enable_eager_execution()

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'enable_eager_execution'
```

I could not find documentation on TensorFlow 2. Nor could I run an older version of TensorFlow:

```
[In:]
!pip install tensorflow==1.12.0
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

[Out:]
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow==1.12.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.12.0) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.1.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.12.0) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: astor>=0.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.12.0) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.12.0) (3.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: gast>=0.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.12.0) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<1.13.0,>=1.12.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.12.0) (1.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.12.0) (0.32.3)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.12.0) (1.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.12.0) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.12.0) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-applications>=1.0.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.12.0) (1.0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.12.0) (1.14.6)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from protobuf>=3.6.1->tensorflow==1.12.0) (40.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorboard<1.13.0,>=1.12.0->tensorflow==1.12.0) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorboard<1.13.0,>=1.12.0->tensorflow==1.12.0) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from keras-applications>=1.0.6->tensorflow==1.12.0) (2.8.0)
2.0.0-dev20190130
```

And [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51888118/how-to-downgrade-tensorflow-version-in-colab) from 5 months ago suggests that we cannot downgrade Tensorflow versions.

Is it possible to enable eager execution on Google Colab?

Comment: On TF 2.0 eager mode will be the default one, so no need to enable it (hence the removal of the `enable_eager..` method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In TensorFlow 2.0 Eager execution is enabled by default. No need to set it up.

Comment: How to turn it off?

Comment: @mathtick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53429896/how-do-i-disable-tensorflows-eager-execution

Comment: Why then executing_eagerly() returns false, and mytensor.numpy() does not exist?
Google colab, tf version 2.12.0