# Cannot downgrade scipy package in Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, google-colaboratory

I'm new in Google Collab and I cannot downgrade a version of scipy I am needing for.

I did what [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51888118/how-to-downgrade-tensorflow-version-in-colab/54445624) suggests, installing old version using pip or pip3, but I am still having the version I don't want it.

## My code:

```
!pip3 install scipy==1.2.1
import scipy
print(scipy.__version__)
```

## I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: scipy==1.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scipy==1.2.1) (1.18.2)
1.4.1
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

## My google colab:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select

```
MENU > Runtime > Restart runtime...
```

Then check again.

```
import scipy
print(scipy.__version__)
```

[image]

Comment: I have it in my language, where is the menu do you refer? could you share an image? see my edited post

Comment: The 5th one. `Entorno de ejecucion`