# How to downgrade Keras in colab ? "NotFoundError: No algorithm worked!"

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I was getting the error **"NotFoundError: No algorithm worked!"** on an architecture that was developed based on the older versions of tensorflow (pre-2.0.0 versions), and that is run on Colab.
Now, Google Colab has an updated version of Tensorflow (post-2.0.0 versions) and Keras.

Following the question that was asked here I downgraded Tensorflow to 1.15.0 : [How to downgrade tensorflow version in colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51888118/how-to-downgrade-tensorflow-version-in-colab)
I used this command to downgrade Tensorflow :

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.15.0 
import tensorflow as tf
```

Still, I have a problem importing Keras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, I downgraded the Keras version to 2.2.4 using this command :

```
!pip install keras==2.2.4
```